# Is there a way I can play video audio out of either the left or right audio channels?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am creating a custom video player using Javascript, HTML and CSS. The video player needs a feature in which the user can swap between the left and right audio channels. However, I noticed that the video properties do not seem to support L-R channel switching, is there a possible way I can work around this?

**UPDATE**
I had originally not phrased the question as I should have (my bad). What I am trying to do is access the sounds on one channel and redirect them to play through both speakers. E.g. If I had a single audio file which contained rain forest noises and bird cheeps play through the left channel and frog croaks on the right channel, I would want to only play what is on the right channel e.g. the frog croaks.

**UPDATE**
I am attempting to split the nodes however am struggling with the implementation, the example I found is for AudioBuffer and does not use an  file. How do I get the audio context to use the audio file and set the destination of the manipulated back to that same audio file in a playable manner? I would ideally need to be able to have functions which could switch off either channel e.g. playFrogNoises() and playBirdNoises()

```
<body>
  <audio id="myAudio" src="audio/Squirrel Nut Zippers - Trou Macacq.mp3"></audio>
</body>
<script>
  var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio')
  var context = new AudioContext();
  var audioSource = context.createMediaElementSource(myAudio)
  var splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2);
  audioSource.connect(splitter);
  var merger = context.createChannelMerger(2)

  //REDUCE VOLUME OF LEFT CHANNEL ONLY
  var gainNode = context.createGain();
  gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.5, context.currentTime);
  splitter.connect(gainNode, 0);

  //CONNECT SPLITTER BACK TO SECOND INPUT OF THE MERGER
  gainNode.connect(merger, 0, 1);
  splitter.connect(merger, 1, 0);

  var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

  merger.connect(destination)

  myAudio.play()

</script>
```

Comment: Do you need to swap channels?  As in, R plays on L, and L plays on R?  Or, do you just need to pan all the channels on a particular channel?  Or, do you need to adjust the balance between L/R?

Comment: I suppose adjust the balance. I would need them to hear what is on the right channel at some points and what's on the left channel at others. And preferably for what is on the channel to play through both speakers

Comment: @graystech reading your update, I understood that what you need is exactly what I need :) Is it possible you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use WebAudio Api with paneer node.

(or what you need, basically you can do everything with you audio channels in that way)

[PannerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode)

```js
<video id="my-video" controls
       src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

const context = new AudioContext(),
    audioSource = context.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById("my-video")),
    panner = context.createStereoPanner();
audioSource.connect(panner);
panner.connect(context.destination);

// Configure panner -1 left and 1 for right. 
panner.pan.setValueAtTime(-1, context.currentTime)
```

Comment: This solution worked! It was just not what I was actually looking for(but that is due to the phrasing of my question, apologies)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelSplitterNode

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelMergerNode\

Comment: you can split channels set gain for each and the mix them together in desired relation.  or mix both channell togetehr to mono and send this mono to both channels. just read more about web audio api.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for the brilliant answer.
When I try to access a video on another server, I get the following error after  context.createMediaElementSource():
MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for URL_TO_MY_VIDEO

I have tried audioSource.mediaElement.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; but it doesn't work.
Do you know how to get it work with a video on another server?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If there is corss protection that means server does not return header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. Only think you can do is make a call by some proxy (your or some public [proxy server](https://nordicapis.com/10-free-to-use-cors-proxies/)).

Comment: @Robert thank you for your answer. I copied your example as is, but nothing happens when I click on play. The audio does not start. If I comment out the code, the audio plays perfectly fine. Any idea What am I missing?